# Use strong induction to prove the ones digit of 4^k.

Tags: induction

The question is to prove the following using strong induction:

"For 4^k, where k is a nonnegative integer, if k is even then the ones digit of 4^k is 6 and if k is odd then the ones digit of 4^k is 4."

The problem also hints at using the quotient-remainder theorem (n = dq + r). By setting d = 10, r would be the ones digit of n. I don't know how to connect this with the problem.

I've been thinking about this problem for literally hours and have no idea what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you multiply a number that ends in a 6 by 4?  What about if the number ends in a 4 instead?

Comment: Okay, I see that pattern. But I still don't know how to apply the idea to strong induction.

Comment: Induction is just a rigorous way of saying "the pattern continues."  And you know *why* the pattern continues, so just write that as an induction argument.

Comment: So I need to prove the 4 x 6 thing first? I don't think this is what the instructor is looking for. I forgot to mention at first, but I need to use the quotient-remainder theorem as well. I updated the original question to explain. Have you seen my username? I have no idea what I'm doing here.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with a relatively simple induction – the easiest way would probably be to note that $4^3 \equiv 4 \pmod{10}$, and therefore, for all $n\geq 1$,  $4^{2n+1} \equiv 4 \pmod{10}$ and $4^{2n+2} = (4^{2n+1})\cdot4 \equiv 16 \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$, the first identity being proved by induction.

I'll leave you to fill in the specific details for the induction hypothesis and induction step.

Comment: Problem is I absolutely suck at induction. I have no idea what to do. How do I prove that 4^(2n) mod 10 = 6 and 4^(2n+1) mod 10 = 4? I'm still very lost.